# newtonsoft json.net disable scientific notation

Tags: json.net, scientific-notation

I would like my webapi to serialize json using camelcase.  So i added the following to Global.asax.

```
        HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = false;
```

What i noticed is that because i set UseDataContractJsonSerializer to false,  big decimals are serialized using scientific notation.   How can i keep camelcase and at the same time disable scientific notation ?

Thanks